# Do I need to state everything in the derived table in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have encounter some confuses when writing queries:

1. Do I need to state everything in the subquery so as to use in the outermost query?
2. I am calculating the average revenue for each high school graduation rate(msa_high) group, but teradata keeps informing " Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group."

Appreciate any helps, thanks a lot !

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN subquery.msa_high>=50 AND subquery.msa_high<=60 THEN 'low'
WHEN subquery.msa_high>=60.1 AND subquery.msa_high <=70 THEN 'medium'
WHEN subquery.msa_high>70 THEN 'high'
END AS rate,
SUM(subquery.amt)/COUNT(DISTINCT subquery.saledate) as AvgRevenue
FROM (SELECT s.store, SUM(t.amt)/COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate), s.msa_high
      FROM trnsact t JOIN store_msa s
      ON t.store=s.store
      WHERE t.stype='P' 
      AND (t.saledate NOT BETWEEN DATE '2005-08-01' AND LAST_DAY(DATE '2005-08-27'))
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate)>20) as subquery
GROUP BY rate;
```

The accurate query is as followed, thanks to the helps:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN subquery.msa_high>=50 AND subquery.msa_high<=60 THEN 'low'
WHEN subquery.msa_high>=60.1 AND subquery.msa_high <=70 THEN 'medium'
WHEN subquery.msa_high>70 THEN 'high'
END AS rate,
SUM(subquery.amt)/SUM(subquery.saledate) as AvgRevenue
FROM (SELECT s.store, s.msa_high, SUM(t.amt) as amt, COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate) as saledate
      FROM trnsact t JOIN store_msa s
      ON t.store=s.store
      WHERE t.stype='P' 
      AND (t.saledate NOT BETWEEN DATE '2005-08-01' AND LAST_DAY(DATE '2005-08-27'))
      GROUP BY s.store, s.msa_high
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate)>20) as subquery
GROUP BY rate;
```

Comment: 1. `YES`, 2. Your subquery does not contain `GROUP BY` clause. Add `GROUP BY s.store, s.msa_high`

Comment: Hi John,  
I have edit the query as told, but then it gives me `All expressions in a derived table must have an explicit name.`

Comment: `SUM(t.amt)/COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate)` => `SUM(t.amt)/COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate) AS AVG_REVENUE`

Comment: Hi John, `Column/Parameter 'subquery.amt' does not exist.`, that's what it told me.

Comment: it's impossible to state `amt` and `COUNT(DISTINCT saledate)` in the subquery because it already has aggragated value

Comment: of course, because in your subquery, you did not have `amt` column. *you need to state everything in the subquery so as to use in the outermost query*

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate? Is *average revenue* the average of the sum of the daily amounts per store/msa group? Is there any msa < 50, how to deal with them? `store` is the Primary Key of `store_msa`?

Comment: @dnoeth I am calculating the the average daily revenue for high school graduation rate group, which is `msa_high`. The lowest rate is above 50 so don't worry :)

Comment: @dnoeth we have answer in the following discussion, please have a look there :)

Comment: @JohnWoo If I rename `SUM(t.amt)` as `tamt` in the subquery, would I be able to use `SUM(subquery.amt)` in the outermost quey? Since I have state it in the innermost query. Thank you for the review :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use all the `Non-Aggregated` columns in the `GROUP BY` Clause.

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN subquery.msa_high>=50 AND subquery.msa_high<=60 THEN 'low'
WHEN subquery.msa_high>=60.1 AND subquery.msa_high <=70 THEN 'medium'
WHEN subquery.msa_high>70 THEN 'high'
END AS rate,
SUM(subquery.amt)/SUM(subquery.saledate) as AvgRevenue
FROM (SELECT s.store, SUM(t.amt)as amt,COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate) as saledate, s.msa_high
      FROM trnsact t JOIN store_msa s
      ON t.store=s.store
      WHERE t.stype='P' 
      AND (t.saledate NOT BETWEEN DATE '2005-08-01' AND LAST_DAY(DATE '2005-08-27'))
      GROUP BY s.store, s.msa_high
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate)>20) as subquery
GROUP BY rate;
```

Comment: thank you, DineshDB, but after I `GROUP BY s.store, s.msa_high` and aliases my calculation, it told me that `'subquery.amt' does not exist.`

Comment: DineshDB, this time `Column/Parameter 'subquery.saledate' does not exist.`

Comment: @DavidHo, I think the outer query doesn't need `COUNT`. We have to use `SUM`.

Comment: Ah! Because we have count them once in the subquery. We just have to sum the number and make a calculation with `SUM(subquery.amt)`

Comment: DineshDB, you're a real genius!

Comment: yes it works! Did you run it yourself or how did you find it?

Comment: @DavidHo, I just go through the query, and find it. If it works then accept the answer as correct, it will help someone.

Comment: The biggest difference is that `rate` only divided by the `COUNT(DISTINCT saledate)` and your `rate` is divide by the `SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT saledate))` :) This is spiritual to me, thank you a lot !

Comment: Assuming that `trnsact` is a huge table and `store` quite small you should apply the subquery aggregation before joining to `store` (the optimizer might be able to do this automatically, check Explain).

Comment: DineshDB, looking for accept button, sorry for the delay, i am new to the website :)

Comment: @DavidHo, no problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @dnoeth it works too! I have wrote it again but I don't know how to show you

Comment: @DavidHo, I'm also glad to meet you. All the best my Friend. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: All the best too. Though I am too rookie to offer any help lol